# Installing shortcut wihout duplicating native handly created one

Tags: java, android, shortcut

I want to add a shortcut to my application, but I cannot manage not to duplicate native handly created one (by using drag and drop on application Icon in Application Menu to Home Screen for example).

Here is my code:

```
public void addShortcut(Context context)
{
    this.manageShortcutAction(context, "com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
}

public void deleteShortcut(Context context)
{
    this.manageShortcutAction(context, "com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
}

private void manageShortcutAction(Context context, String intentAction)
{
    Context applicationContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    Intent shortcut = new Intent(intentAction);
    ApplicationInfo appInfo = applicationContext.getApplicationInfo();
    PackageManager packageManager= applicationContext.getPackageManager();
    String applicationName = (String) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(appInfo);

    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, applicationName); // Shortcut name
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(appInfo.packageName));// Setup activity should be shortcut object 
    shortcut.putExtra("duplicate", false); // Just create once
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(applicationContext, appInfo.icon));// Set shortcut icon

    applicationContext.sendBroadcast(shortcut);
}
```

And my manifest required permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

By the way, I had overwritten the Application code which is now `MainApplication` extending `Application`.
I have already tried to create a component to create the `Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT`, without the expecting result.

If anyone has an idea...

Comment: shortcut.putExtra("duplicate", false); not working in sdk 26 and it will created over and over

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that in order to prevent the app from creating a duplicate of the shortcut created at app installation (or by copying from the menu), I have to create one with the same parameters of the existing one - using the same shortcut name is not enough.

After a lot of testing and thanks to the logcat, I've been able to create an exact replica as follows:

```
private void installShortcut() {
    final Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    shortcutIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon));
    intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

The difference with other answers I found on SO is in these 3 lines:

```
    shortcutIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
```

which I figured out by looking at the log entry printed when manually launching the app using the system created shortcut

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.myapp/.activities.main.MainActivity bnds=[365,73][475,191] } from pid 279
```

Comment: If someone, one day tries to do so, I'll interested of marking this answer as the best one. For now, I have no time to test (and my marketing has asked to me to remove this feature). Thanks for answering.

Comment: According to the last comment (not testing by myself), I change the solved response to this one. I hope it covers all the manufacturer.

Comment: Not working on Marshmallow. Tested on S5 and GAPPS emulator.

Comment: I honestly think it has to do with what kind of launcher app you are using, but I could be wrong.
It wont work with googlequicksearchbox launcher.
It works with AOSP launcher1 (A marshmello tablet im testing with).
However an app called "TopBuzz" seems to have implemented it perfectly, but I dunno how they do it!

Answer (score 0):

After having discuss with Sony's developers, there is no way not to duplicate manually created shortcuts...

I found some methods for Samsung but these were not generic.

Comment: SdkVersion 26 and in Android 6.0 , putExtra("duplicate", false) , not working add all , and it will created over and over !!

Comment: It's not compulsory for home applications/Launcher to manage the shortcuts (even badly).

On Huawei, it's just a copy of Apple Launcher where there is only a list of application and some directories.